# How to downgrade python to 3.7 from 3.8 in Mac m1 big Sur?

Tags: python

I am using Mac m1 Big Sur 11.3.1 version. I want to run a mask rcnn model for a bubble detection purpose. I am unable to downgrade my python version from 3.8.11 to 3.7 without which I cannot use a compatible tensorflow>=1.4.

```
conda search python
```

this is only giving me a list up to 3.8.11 not below that

Answer (score 1):

use  pyenv for that:

```
brew install pyenv
```

To install a specific Python version, run:

```
pyenv install <version>
```

To select a version:

```
pyenv local 3.5.0
```

Note that you must update PATH to override the default Python version:

```
PATH="~/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/bin:${PATH}"
```

to list available versions:

```
pyenv versions
```

see https://gist.github.com/Bouke/11261620 for more information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using brew,

This is as simple as it gets:

```
brew install python@3.7
```

Create a softlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/<VERSION>/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

(
**NOTE: Replace <VERSION> in above path by copying the output of below command**

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/                                                         
3.7.10_3
```

) 
Then Use `python3.7` command to access the python shell :)

Answer (score 0):

I think conda can install the python 3.7 for you, you can try to fix your conda environment first. Here is the conda search python from my laptop, for your reference.

[image: conda search python]